# Wordpress frontend file upload

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload

for a wordpress website I want to make a form with a file upload button. I'm new to wordpress and php and just want to experiment with it.

I've searched on the web and looked in the documentation, it seems clear what you have to do but not where you need to do it. Also free plugins don't do the trick as they only let you upload images to the media library folder as an admin.

I've tried to add a block on a page with custom html and php in it just to test but I got errors and it doesn't seem like the way to go.

Now i'm trying to add the php code in functions.php and in the browser I see that there is a post request but I still don't see the uploaded image on the server.

This is my code in functions.php

```
$upload_dir = '/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/';

if (isset($_POST['ImageToUpload']) && !empty($_FILES)){
    $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"]);
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a page template to create the form and move your code there.
You also need to use form action handler to be same as the page.

For first render the page template will render the form, and when the form is submitted the same page will process the form.

```
<?php

  // Form is Submitted
  if (isset($_POST['ImageToUpload']) && !empty($_FILES)){
    .... rest of the code to process the form 

?>
// Render the form when it is GET Request
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="ImageToUpload" method="post">
<label for="name">Name:</label>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value='' />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the file going to be uploaded to?